# Completely remove windows 7 and install ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I have installed dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu. Now I'm totally into Ubuntu. I found I just have to simply delete the windows 7 by using "Disk utility" in Ubuntu. I did it. Then I wanted to spread my Ubuntu OS to the those partitions as well. Then I find a good video tutorial. It says to use "gparted".

So I'm going to use it. But when I'm checking my hard disk data usage by using Disk utility, I'm a bit confused how to extend the hard disk space for Ubuntu. It shows several partitions. I want to clarify which partitions I should add to Ubuntu. So I have attached a snapshot of my hard disk data usage. Please help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't expand partitions forward on a disk. My advice would be to extend the ext4 (Ubuntu) partition as much as you can (using "edit partition"), and then make another partition in the remaining free space with an ext4 filesystem to use under Ubuntu.

If you only want one partition for Ubuntu, I would boot from the live USB drive and select "Erase everything and install Ubuntu". This will erase everything on your hard drive, so back up your files first (especially your home folder).

Comment: first thanks for the comment.I want to add all the free space to ubuntu and make my computer completely ubuntu.How to do that?

Comment: I edited my response to reflect your question.

Answer (score 0):

- You can add 105 GB and 172 GB unallocated space to your Ubuntu partition.For this first you had to boot Ubuntu live disk.
- Click on try ubuntu option on startup and then open gparted from Dash.Make sure that all your partitions are unmounted.
- Now rightclick on your Ubuntu partition and select Resize/Move option,now you can be able to add 105 GB unallocated space to your ext4 partition by dragging the left arrow to the extreme left.
- Apply the changes.Now your Ubuntu partition size become 135 GB.
- To add 172 GB unallocated space(which was outside the extended partition) with your Ubuntu partition,follow the below .
- Right-click on the extended partition(not your Ubuntu partition) and select Resize option.Add 172 GB unallocated space to your extended partition by dragging the left arrow to the extreme left.Now the 172 GB unallocated space would comes just below to your ext4 partition.
- Add the 172 GB unallocated space,now your Ubuntu partition size will become (172+105+30 GB)

Comment: yeah i'm going to do that way.i saw we can make a gparted bootable cd.i'm referring this video tutorial- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wkh-2tYt1g4 So you have only mentioned about the 105GB space.I want to add that very large 172 GB space to ubuntu also.How to do that?Plz help

Comment: I have already uploaded it.It's not showing to you?For me it's showing in the post.

Comment: Gparted live disk is also a best choice and make sure that all your partitions are unmounted.

Comment: I unmounted all the other partitions.But when i'm trying to unmount the partition which has ubuntu has installed,it gives a error "can't unmount.this partition is currently in use".Why is that?

Comment: Boot ubuntu installation disk.And then run gparted from it.Not on the installed Ubuntu.